# How to customize SurfaceFlinger of Android

Tags: android, android-source

I'd like to verify my designs on SurfaceFlinger on real Android phone/tablet. But I don't have any source code of any devices.

Can I just use source code from AOSP to build a `libsurfaceflinger.so` and push it to phone?

Or can someone recommend some commercial Android devices with Qualcomm SoC and source code support?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I just use source code from AOSP to build a libsurfaceflinger.so and push it to phone?

This is veried. I've tried compile libsurfaceflinger.so for Pixel4 and push the lib file to NXP i.MX8M Plus EVB. It seems to work well.